# .NET Maui - Precompiling failed. The specified response can not be read

Tags: android, maui, aot

The problem is that ahead of time compilator is giving me a lot of errors

[image: Errors AOT]

I've created a new, out of the box, .net MAUI-project. I did just want to view the results of a release for Android bud I immediately got errors when running a release build.

There is a part in the configuration looking like below which indicates that the AOT should not be run:

`

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

`

Comment: Please post error messages as text (just like code), never as images.

Answer (score 6):

A solution is to go the project properties and uncheck the "Enable Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation." under AOT.

After this I could make a release build but I am not sure about the consequences.

[image: AOT]

Comment: Works. but when .net 7 is installed with VS dont forget to update to the latest version because of this error which resolves ignoring this setting https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/79849